# How to stop embedded google drive on my website from linking to Google when clicked on

Tags: hyperlink, google-drive-api, typo3

After having embedded google drive files on my website (awesome feature), I found a minor drawback.

When clicking on one of the maps in the list, it will redirect/link the viewer on my page to the google drive site. However, I want to keep the viewer on my page and the folder to open within my own website.

Also I want other folders within these folders to open within the borders of my website, and so on and so forth.

The used code is simple:

The used website is Typo3 based.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Thank you very much in advance; all replies and suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: used code: <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=0By0jEBL7DBA5V2dzbXFWVXl3SnM#list" width="925" height="450" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

After a quick [search](https://www.google.ch/search?q=google%20drive%20iframe) it seems to me this is more a hack than an official google feature, so probably there's no easy way for altering the behaviour of the stuff inside the iframe. I would rather recommend setting an outbound link and accepting the fact that you're hosting the files at Google.

In the future, there might (or might not) be a File Abstraction Layer Adapter for Drive coming up: http://wiki.typo3.org/FAL_Adapters. Well, probably not so soon. But for Dropbox!